# Pygame not updating the display when trying to print text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to learn PyGame by following this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-text-pygame-screen/).
When I crash the "You've crashed" text only shows up for one tick and disappears almost immediately again. When I run the code on my friends pc it runs perfectly fine.

Video of it happening: [Streamable link](https://streamable.com/3boi5)

What should really happen: Play game -> You Crash -> Text comes up("You dead") -> Wait for 2 seconds -> Game resets

My code is:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
crash = False

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('lil spacey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

characterImage = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Longcat.jpg'), (100,100))

spriteWidth = pygame.Surface.get_width(characterImage)
spriteHeight = pygame.Surface.get_height(characterImage)

def spriteCharacter(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(characterImage, (x, y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messageDisplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    gameLoop()

def crash():
    messageDisplay('You dead')

def gameLoop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        spriteCharacter(x,y)

        if x > display_width - spriteWidth or x < 0:
            crash()
        elif y > display_height - spriteHeight or y < 0:
            crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

What I've tried:

- Reinstalled Python
- Reinstalled Pygame

Versions:

- Python: 3.7.2
- Pygame: 1.9.4
- OS: macOS Mojave

Hope you can help:)

Comment: it is working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window may not get repainted after calling `pygame.display.update()` when you don't let pygame process events.

You could call `pygame.event.get()` between `pygame.display.update()` and `time.sleep(2)`, but you should try to follow these rules:

- have only one main loop
- call `pygame.display.update` once per frame
- never call `time.sleep` or any other long running blocking function
- don't call the main loop function from the main loop function

to prevent such problems.

When a crash happens, you should change the state of your game to reflect this fact, and then count the time until 2 seconds passed, then change the state again.